# Error after cleaning logs in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, logging, truncate

The size of tables of my website (built on Magento) was reaching the limits and I truncated logs (`log_url`,`log_url_info`, `log_visitor`, `log_visitor_info`) via phpMyAdmin. After that when you type the name of the website, the error page comes: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4944' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

I don't know what to do, because we don't have an IT specialist, who can help us.

Another thing is that we transferred our website from its own domain to subdomain (links were updated automatically by our domain provider) some time ago.

Any ideas are appreciated. We can restore the website from the back-up, but it will again have those large tables.

Comment: can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure those were the only tables you truncated... Did the truncate complete cleanly and are the tables empty?

Comment: @JavierC.H. I guess it will be easier to post the weblink to our website. When pasting stack trace, it became very messy. http://gizmos.kinkeraamat.ee

Comment: @AshleySwatton yes, truncated without error messages, everything was OK. 2 days passed since I last truncated them, and they are not empty anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message I would advise you clean the logs again. Take the site offline if possible and run the following on your database;

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

I don't think you've done all the tables and because you issued a truncate and not a delete magento is now trying to create records in related tables usings IDs that already exist.